# IIE 6.0 not recognizing index.php as Default document

Tags: php, iis-6

This morning our server stopped recognizing index.php as th default document. It goes to the 404 error page. This has been working since we set it up several years ago. If you go to the index.php page it finds it just fine. I have tried to put a static version of the page up as index.htm, index.html, Default.htm etc but none of them seem to be recognized even though all are listed as default documents in the website document properties. There are no 301 permanent redirect's to cause this I just need to know how to troubleshoot this issue. Im a developer, not so much a server admin.

Answer (score 0):

Start by checking your [default documents setup](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/dc6eb1b4-9028-4308-9935-52b64edfad36.mspx?mfr=true), of course. The link explains how to add/sort/verify them; it's cake.

Have you rebooted the server? It's, dare I say, Microsoft. They do love the reboot.

It's not a permissions issue or configuration problem (other than possibly default doc) if you can type in the document and see it. So I think your issue will be solved by one of the two above.

Comment: Ive done the default documents setup and restarted IIS and the server itself and im still getting a 404 if I go to the root of the site, but not if I go to index.php :(